# driver.get(url) sometimes not working in a loop

Tags: function, selenium, browser

Sometimes driver.get(url) function is not working in a loop without any error and logs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--disable-webgl")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
path = r'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,options=options)

for x in range(1000):
    url = "https://www.palabrasaleatorias.com/random-words.php"
    driver.get(url)
    url = "https://www.google.ru/imghp?hl=ru"
    print(x,"Test[1]")
    driver.get(url)
    print(x,"Test[2]")
driver.close()
```

Is that selenium bug with the function driver.get or what?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding some sleep statements (in case the url takes some time to load):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--disable-webgl")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
path = r'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,options=options)

for x in range(1000):

    url = "https://www.palabrasaleatorias.com/random-words.php"
    driver.get(url)

    # waiting for 3 seconds for the url to load
    time.sleep(5)

    url = "https://www.google.ru/imghp?hl=ru"

    # waiting for 3 seconds for the next url to load
    time.sleep(3)

    print(x, "Test[1]")
    driver.get(url)
    print(x, "Test[2]")

driver.close()
```